# Map Annotation reusing

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I created custom map annotation (`MKPointAnnotation`).

When I click on this annotation on map it performs segue. Problem occurs when I dismiss view that was showed. When I come back on map view I can't reuse this annotation. I can reuse it only if i open another one and than come back to first.

This how I am performing the segue from map annotation.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    let annotation = view.annotation as! CustomSpot
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "infoSegue", sender: annotation)

    return

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to deselect the annotation:

```
view.setSelected(false, animated: false)
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: As the documentation warns us, do _not_ call this method: "You should not call this method directly. An `MKMapView` object calls this method in response to user interactions with the annotation."